# Laravel 5.4 Relations are not loading inside Model boot method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a model named 'Poll'.  Inside Poll model I defined a boot method like follows:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::created(function($model){
       // dd($model);
       $speakers = $model->speakers()->get();
       // dd($speakers);

       // What I want to do here is: create poll options relation from speakers as follows
       // $poll->poll_options()->create([
       //     'option' => $speaker->name,
       // ]);
    }
}
```

I am adding the speakers relation and it is working perfect.

But inside this boot method, inside self::created if I tried to get the speakers relation, it is always empty (dd($speakers) line). Is it because of the boot method runs just after the model is saved into DB and the relations not at all saved?

I am getting newly created model in the line:  dd($model) mentioned in the code.

**UPDATE**

I tried with events also.
My Poll Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use Cookie;
use App\Events\PollCreated;

class Poll extends Model
{
  ........
  protected $events = [
        'created' => PollCreated::class,
    ];
  .......

  public function speakers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Speaker','poll_speaker','poll_id','speaker_id');
  }
}
```

app/Events/PollCreated.php:

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Poll;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PollCreated
{
  use SerializesModels;

  public $poll;

  /**
   * Create a new event instance.
   *
   * @param  Poll  $poll
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Poll $poll)
  {
      // $this->poll = $poll;
      $event = $poll->event()->first();
      // dd($event);
      // dd($poll->speakers()->get());
      // dd($poll->load('speakers'));
  }
}
```

Here also I am not getting speakers, in the line: dd($poll->speakers()->get());

my Speaker model:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

    class Speaker extends Model
    {
    use CrudTrait;
    ……..

        public function polls()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Poll');
        }
    ……..
    }
```

Comment: You mean `$model->speakers()->get();` under `parent::boot()` and not inside `self::created()`?

Comment: Inside self::created(). I will update the question.

Comment: can't you `->load('speakers')`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with $speakers?  Do you want the array available to your views?

Comment: @DomDaFonte No. I want to create some other model data by getting the 
 speakers relation data.

Comment: @Tschallacka I tried: dd($poll->load('speakers')); but I am getting the poll Model. inside it shows:
` #relations: array:1 [▼
    "speakers" => Collection {#752 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]`

Comment: show us how you defined the relationship for speakers

Comment: @Tschallacka Updated Question with Speaker model

Comment: Okay. so you're using an intermediate table. Now you're `creating` the poll model. The primary key of the poll model will only be known after or during the created event. Relationships cannot be bound before that or inserted into the database unless you use a form of deferred binding like octobercms does. Do you use deferred binding? Where do you associate the relationships? can you show that code?

Comment: as @Tschallacka suggest to use $poll->load('speakers'). 
I think that should work.
Write $model->speakers instead of $model->speakers()->get();

Comment: @TuhinBepari I tried 

$poll->load('speakers');
dd($poll->speakers());

but no data in speakers relation

Comment: You mention `Is it because of the boot method runs just after the model is saved into DB and the relations not at all saved?`. This makes me think you're not actually saving the speakers. And the parent model would need to be saved/created before you can save any belongs to relations.

Comment: No. The boot method calling before the many to many through another table relation creates. But in my example the event relation (belongs to) is saved already. But ManyToMany through another table is not saved at the time of boot.

Comment: @Tschallacka I defined the relations in the models as shown above. You want  to see the Providers that I defined in app.php? Or which binding code you like to see? And can you tell me one good way of creating poll options from poll 's speakers after the poll is created?

Comment: @Abhi - if the relations aren't saved, you're not going to be able to query them from the database. You _might_ be able to access them via the relation property. E.g. `$model->speakers`, if you have attached them to the model.

Comment: Yes, I want a solution for this.

Comment: @Abhi, what does that mean? Have you attached them to the model or not?

Comment: @ahbi show the code where you actually create the model and attach the speakers. the "using" code

Comment: I am using the backpack crud for that (Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController - check storeCrud function). Don't worry about I am perfectly attaching the speakers relations to Model. Because I am getting that relations attached after the boot function. I AM DOING IT RIGHT. Speakers are attaching to the model. Only problem is speakers I am not getting inside boot method self::created because poll_speakers join table is not created at that time.

Comment: Anyway I can do another work around for this by it adding that inside my Controller action 'store' function. But I dont think its the best way to do that. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with laravel 5.6

Comment: Actually it is working for me in Laravel 5.6, my problem was that I had a Relationship called `fromAccount` and I was trying to call it as `from_account` property. When I called it as `fromAccount` - it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with timing as models must always be created before they can be set in a many-to-many relationship. So there is no possible way that in a many-to-many relationship during the `created` event the relationship is already set as the `created` events are always raised before the relationships.

Anyone looking for a solution can probably experiment with the [chelout/laravel-relationship-events](https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events) package as this adds relationship events to models.

To be sure, I tested this out with a simple application of users and computers.

**User.php**

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use HasBelongsToManyEvents;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function($model){
           Log::info('user::created');
        });

        static::belongsToManyAttaching(function ($relation, $parent, $ids) {
            $ids = implode(' & ', $ids);
            Log::info("Attaching {$relation} {$ids} to user.");
        });

        static::belongsToManyAttached(function ($relation, $parent, $ids) {
            $ids = implode(' & ', $ids);
            Log::info("Computers {$ids} have been attached to user.");
        });
    }

    public function computers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Computer::class, 'user_computers');
    }
}
```

Computer class is the same in reverse. And for the following code:

```php
$user = User::create();

$user->computers()->attach([
    Computer::create()->id,
    Computer::create()->id
]);
```

This was the outcome:

```php
user::created  
computer::created  
computer::created  
Attaching computers 69 & 70 to user.  
Computers 69 & 70 have been attached to user.
```